# Deselect only text with one certain class on mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, text, unselect

Let's say I have some text with the class `.a` and some more text with the class `.b`.

How to unselect only text with the class `.a` on mousemove, instead of all text like in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lx5bbrk2/

```
$('*').mousemove(function(){
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); //deselects all text, needs to be modified
});
```

I don't know how to put selector into this.

note: select text with ctrl+a or with double click.

**edit:**

nevermind `span`s. this fiddle is just a quick illustration. real situation is simple - different text classes are in different divs.

different classes are also different element types - spans and contenteditable divs. doesn't really matter how certain text gets deselected, as long as it's not the whole document.

So is this even possible?

Comment: What behavior would you like if the selection is like [element of class `b`][element of class `a`][element of class `b`]? Do you want to end up with two selections for each of the elements of class `b` (generally browsers don't support this)?

Comment: I don't have this kind of situation, fiddle with spans is just for simple illustration. Basically, .a is actually a class of contenteditable divs which I want to exclude from deselecting.

Comment: so different text classes are in separate divs. simple situation but I can't find the solution.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do on mousemove is something like the following: 1) check what is currently selected, recording elements that are not of class `a`, 2) deselect everything, 3) re-select the recorded elements (i.e. those not of class `a`). I don't remember the details of how to do this at the moment though.